# Calculate nothing

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

This is a [mobile friendly puzzle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles):

```
Unless pure nuns use pulse 
917    655  1901 104 614
```

=> Calculate `NULL`

Comment: I even created this puzzle completely on my smartphone :)

Comment: Are there rot13(fhccbfrq gb or cnggreaf orgjrra gur jbeqf, be vf guvf shapgvba cheryl qrcraqrag ba gur jbeqf gurzfryirf? Orpnhfr V tbg gur vzcerffvba gung gur jbeqf pbhyq pbeerfcbaq gb n pelcgvp pyhr)...

Comment: @newQOpenWid, there is no cryptic clue. Just thought it would be nicer to put the words in a sentence.

Comment: Been a while, but is this related to conversions between bases? I tried converting between base 10 and base 7 and back, but I didn't get any progress...

Comment: not at all, it is something completely different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is

> a cipher for Roman numerals: `selrupn = IVXLCDM`.
>
>  `unless pure nuns use pulse`
>  `CMXVII DCLV MCMI CIV DCXIV`
>  `917    655  1901 104 614`
>   So `null` = `MCXX` = 1120.